# What would be the best practice to merge additional variables to data based on specific row information when web scraping in R using 'rvest'?

Tags: r, web-scraping, data.table, apply, rvest

I'm currently web scraping the IMDB website to extract movie data.

I would like to know how you would solve this problem.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(rvest)
library(janitor)

#top rated movies website 
url <- 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250'

# extract the title of the movies using rvest

titles <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(' .titleColumn a') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.data.table() %>%
  setnames(. ,old = colnames(.), new='title') 

# extract links to each of the titles, this will be the reference 

links <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('.titleColumn a') %>%
  html_attr('href') %>%
  as.data.table() %>%
  setnames(. ,old = colnames(.), new='links') 

# creating a DT with the data

movies <- cbind(titles,links)
```

I will have movies DT with title and links as columns.

Now, I will like to extract additional data of each movie using the links

I will continue using the first row as an example.

```
#the first link in movies  

link <- 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=NJ52X0MM1V9FKSPBT46G&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_1'

# selector for budget data (this will not change)

select <- '.txt-block:nth-child(15) , .txt-block:nth-child(14) , #titleDetails .txt-block:nth-child(13) , #titleDetails .txt-block:nth-child(12)'


# get budget data

budget <- link %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(select) %>%
  html_text() %>%
  gsub('\\n','',.) %>%
  str_split(.,'\\:')%>%
  as.data.table() %>%
  janitor::row_to_names(row_number = 1) %>%
  setnames(.,old=colnames(.),new= tolower(gsub(' ','_' , str_trim(colnames(.)))))

budget[,(colnames(budget))] <- lapply(budget,function(x) str_extract_all(x, "(\\$) *([0-9,]+)"))
```

Now I have a 1x4 table with budget information

I would like to pull data for each link of movies and merge it into DT to have a final DT with 6 columns; 'title', 'link' + four budget variables.  I was trying to create a function that includes the code to get the budget data using each row's link as a parameter and the using 'lapply', I don't think this is the correct approach.

I would like to see if you have a solution to this in an efficient way.

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would solve your problem:

```
# selector for budget data (this will not change)
select <- '.txt-block:nth-child(15) , .txt-block:nth-child(14) , #titleDetails .txt-block:nth-child(13) , #titleDetails .txt-block:nth-child(12)'

# get budget data
## As function
get_budget = function(link,select){
budget <- link %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(select) %>%
  html_text() %>%
  gsub('\\n','',.) %>%
  str_split(.,'\\:')%>%
  as.data.table() %>%
  janitor::row_to_names(row_number = 1) %>%
  setnames(.,old=colnames(.),new= tolower(gsub(' ','_' , str_trim(colnames(.)))))

budget[,(colnames(budget))] <- lapply(budget,function(x) str_extract_all(x, "(\\$) *([0-9,]+)"))
return(budget)
}

#As your code is slow I'll subset movies to have 10 rows:
movies = movies[1:10,]
tmp = 
lapply(movies[, links], function(x) 
  get_budget(link = paste0("https://www.imdb.com/",x),select=select )) %>% 
  rbindlist(., fill = T)

movies = cbind(movies, tmp)
```

And your result would seem like this: [movies_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr0yj.png)

Finally, I think this little advice would make your code loke cooler:

- `setnames` doesn't need `.` from `magrittr`; it automatically understands your kind of code.
- When possible avoid using `setnames(. ,old = colnames(.), new='links')`. In your case is just necessary `setnames('links')` since you are renaming all your variables.
- `setnames(dt,old = oldnames, new=newnames)` is only necessary when oldnames is not equal to names(dt).
- Since `DT` is another `R` popular library, completely unrelated with `data.table` I think is better to refer to a data.table as what is a `data.table`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your suggestions were helpful!